# How to create an erlydtl custom tag?

Tags: erlang, erlydtl

The [docs](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl) say:

"Starting with release 0.9.1, the recommended way to add custom tags and filters are to register a module"

How does one *register* a module with erlydtl?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here the team that maintains the project is very responsive on their dedicated group mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/zotonic-developers

Comment: @Amiramix What is "zotonic"?

Comment: Oh well, it's an Erlang CMS that extensively uses `erlydtl` when generating web pages http://zotonic.com/docs/0.13/developer-guide/templates.html It could be a custom version but many developers contribute to both projects, so very likely they will be aware of the changes happening in the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer at https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/issues/238

It's the options that refers to library you want (from the [Readme](https://github.com/erlydtl/erlydtl/blob/master/README.markdown)):

> `libraries` - A list of `{Name, Module}` libraries implementing custom tags and filters. Module should implement the `erlydtl_library` behaviour.

And:

> `default_libraries` - A list of libraries that should be loaded by default when compiling a template. Libraries can be specified either by name (when there is a name to module mapping also provided in the `libraries` option) or by module.

If you register a library, but doesn't load it by default, you can load it from a template with the `{% load libname %}` tag.